# Debugging iOS: How do I break on property value change?

Tags: objective-c, ios, debugging, properties, gdb

I am trying to find out how a `UIView`s transformation matrix is being modified. Thus (using the `gdb` console) I'd like to watch for any/all changes of the `UIView`'s `transform` property. How would I go about doing so?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Add a symbolic breakpoint in Xcode. Use `-[UIView setTransform:]` as the Symbol.

Use a more narrow subclass class if you want less or more specific output.

Comment: @JimThio, in Xcode debugger pane, type + button, choose Symbolic Breakpoint.

Comment: Note: Auto completion has no hints for property setter.

Answer (score 13):

Use a symbolic breakpoint `-[UIView setTransform:]`. Note that you can also use a condition with $arg1 (works only on 64bit simulator like iphone 5s) compared to some pointer to catch breakpoints on property change only for a specific instance `$arg1 == 0x7f9cbba75e60`. Screenshot below shows a breakpoint that catches changes on transform property only for UIView instance that has a pointer 0x7f9cbba75e60

[image: xcode symbolic breakpoint]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it doesn't require a custom subclass.

Answer (score 0):

If you're like me, and don't write in Obj-C, here's a quick Swift way to do it for beginners.

[image]

Just add a `didSet` to the property, and a breakpoint inside the block.